# how to sql select query by value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql log table that logs database table events. (insert, update, delete)

```
event_id    event_name    table     feature_id
1           insert          x       5
2           update          x       5
3           update          x       5
4           delete          x       5
5           insert          x       9
5           update          x       9
```

So I want to select this table. But, for a feature_id:

- if the last `event_name` is `delete`, select only this row not before rows, else select all.

For the above table, the select result should be like:

```
event_id    event_name    table     feature_id
4           delete          x       5
5           insert          x       9
5           update          x       9
```

Because the last record for 5 event_name `delete`. I could not create an sql query for this.

Answer (score 0):

try like below using cte

```
with cte as
(
select min(event_id) from table_name where event_name='delete'
) select * from table_name where event_id>=( select event_id from cte)
```

or simply using subquery

```
select * from table_name where event_id>=(select min(event_id) from table_name where event_name='delete')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select * from TABLENAME
where event_name = 'Delete'

union 

select * from TABLENAME
where event_id >= (select event_id from TABLENAME where event_name = 'Delete')
```

Comment: why you do union?, your concept is just a copy of zaynul's answer - isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I use max(event_id) to prevent error if Table1 has multiple event_name with 'delete' value. If I omit max, the subquery returns more than one value. You can use other aggregate, eg. min(event_id).

```
with cte as
(
    select event_id from Table1 where event_name = 'delete'
)
select * from Table1 where event_id >= (select max(event_id) from cte)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to get the difference of the max event_id and the max event_id with event_name = 'delete' and use it in the WHERE clause:

```
with cte as (
    select 
      (max(event_id) - max(case when event_name = 'delete' then event_id else 0 end)) dif,
      max(case when event_name = 'delete' then event_id else 0 end) maxid
    from tablename where feature_id = 5
)
select * 
from tablename t
where (feature_id <> 5 or event_id = (select maxid from cte))
or (select dif from cte) <> 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=02317293ac4e489c500952d1b2cfecc9).
Results:

```
> event_id | event_name | table | feature_id
> -------: | :--------- | :---- | ---------:
>        4 | delete     | x     |          5
>        5 | insert     | x     |          9
>        5 | update     | x     |          9
```

If there is another row for feature_id = 5 like:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (event_id,event_name,"table",feature_id) VALUES 
(6,'update','x',5)
```

then the results is:

```
> event_id | event_name | table | feature_id
> -------: | :--------- | :---- | ---------:
>        1 | insert     | x     |          5
>        2 | insert     | x     |          5
>        3 | insert     | x     |          5
>        4 | delete     | x     |          5
>        5 | insert     | x     |          9
>        5 | update     | x     |          9
>        6 | update     | x     |          5
```

Comment: delete event may be multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `'delete'` can only appear once as the last record, you can do:

```
select *
from table_name
where event_id >= all (select t2.event_id
                       from table_name t2
                       where t2.feature_id = t.feature_id and                             
                             t2.event_name = 'delete'
                      );
```

Otherwise, this gets a bit more complicated:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(event_name) over (partition by feature_id order by event_id desc) as last_event_name,
             row_number() over (partition by feature_id order by event_id desc) as seqnum
      from my_table t
     ) t
where (last_event_name = 'delete' and seqnum = 1) or
      (last_event_name <> 'delete');
```

The `where` clause can be simplified to:

```
where last_event_name <> 'delete' or seqnum = 1
```